# How to add a while loop counter to this code

Tags: python

I believe that this code is fairly self-explanatory but I am confused as to how to implement a counter.

The code is for a guessing game

```
from random import randint

computer_guess = randint(0,10)

def endGame(computer_guess):
    print("Cheerio")
    finalOption = True
    import sys
    if 10/5 == 2:
        sys.exit()

def menu(computer_guess):

    finalOption = False
    while not finalOption:
        print("Welcome to this number guessing game sir")
        print("You must see if you can guess my number...")
        mainGame()

def mainGame():
        anyInput = int(input('Give me your guess'))


        if (anyInput == computer_guess):
                print ("Well done, you got my number")
                finalOption = True
                endGame(computer_guess)

        elif (computer_guess > anyInput):
                print ("You need to go higher")
                mainGame()


        elif (anyInput > computer_guess):
                print ("You need to go lower")
                mainGame()

menu(computer_guess)
```

Apologies for the gaps in the code

Comment: please explain the behavior you wish to achieve

Comment: What do you want the counter to count and what decision do you want to make depend on its value?

Comment: What is `is 10/5 == 2` for? Since you're using Python3 this should always be true.

Comment: I would like to count the amount of times it is ran, so the player may see the amount of guesses they have had.

Comment: The 10/5 is just there, why not?

Comment: "Why not"? Why? You shouldn't be putting in anything that's "just there."

Answer (score 0):

try the following pattern

```
count = 1
while true:
  guess = get input...
  if guess > answer: 
    say something...
  else if guess < answer: 
    say something...
  else: 
    exit with count...
  count++
```

Answer (score 0):

I find that a class structure like

```
class MyGame:
    def __init__(self, options):
        # set up initial game state

    def play(self):
        # play one full game;
        # return WIN or LOSE when the game is over

    def one_round(self):
        # play one round;
        # return WIN, LOSE if the game is over,
        #   or CONTINUE to keep playing
```

makes it easier to think about a game. This becomes something like

```
from random import randint

LOSE, WIN, CONTINUE = 0, 1, 2

class GuessingGame:
    def __init__(self, low=1, high=10, guesses=10):
        self.low     = low
        self.high    = high
        self.prompt  = "\nGive me your guess [{}-{}]: ".format(low, high)
        self.turn    = 0
        self.guesses = guesses
        self.target  = randint(low, high)

    def play(self):
        print("Welcome to this number guessing game sir")
        print("You must see if you can guess my number...")
        while self.turn < self.guesses:
            result = self.get_guess()
            if result == WIN:
                return WIN
        # ran out of guesses!
        print("Sorry, you lost! My number was {}.".format(self.target))
        return LOSE

    def get_guess(self):
        self.turn += 1
        # repeat until you get a valid guess
        while True:
            try:
                num = int(input(self.prompt))
                if self.low <= num <= self.high:
                    break
            except ValueError:
                print("It has to be an integer!")
        # find the result
        if num < self.target:
            print("You need to go higher!")
            return CONTINUE
        elif num == self.target:
            print("Well done, you guessed the number.")
            return WIN
        else:
            print("You need to go lower!")
            return CONTINUE

def main():
    results = [0, 0]
    while True:
        result = GuessingGame().play()
        results[result] += 1
        print("\nYou have {} losses and {} wins.".format(*results))
        yn = input("Do you want to play again [y/n]? ").strip().lower()
        if yn in ["n", "no"]:
            break

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```